# IIS 10 Can't bind port 443

Tags: iis-10

I had to rebuild my development server because of a small meltdown.  Anyways fresh 2016 install with IIS.  I created a new site and am trying to bind to port 443 and for some reason IIS stopping web site and says port is in use.  It is not in use the only other site is the default web site and I turned it off.

The site has a unique host header -- domain.com

in binding select add

input the host header and change the port from 80 to 443

add binding and the website is stopped, try to start it and I get IIS error port in use.

I have done this before without incident I have no idea why this is happening any help would be appreciated

-----------------EDIT-----------------

I was in a hurry when I posted this question (Lunch) and left out a piece of information.  There is one more site on the server and it's configured to use PHP (first time using php on IIS)it is bound on just port 80 in IIS.  sorry for the lack of information.

Comment: Your server is probably configured to serve non SSL on port 80 and SSL enabled on port 443 by default. And you are trying to change the non SSL  to use port 443.

Comment: I set this all up before, however I could have forgotten something.  The way I remember it was I ran lets-encrypt-simple and it bound the port during certificate install.  This time I installed the certificate but did not get a port binding for the site.  That's when I just opened bindings and chose add binding entered host name and changed the port 80 to 443 giving me two bindings.  one on 80 one on 443 but the site went down and when I tried to start it it claims another site is using 443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alvits --- sent me in the right direction....

when you add the binding for ssl you have to change the type to https.  I didn't change the type leaving it http and just changing the port 443 this will not work.  Another half a day wasted because I'm a noob.